# Windows bat - search in file for string and get next results in a variable

Tags: batch-file

How can i search in a file "C:\x.txt" for string "this is dummy text" and get next results from same line in a variable to use later in an echo %var%.

x.txt is:

`first line
some text as this is dummy text: secret
last line`

Thanks!

Comment: Do not post an answer unless it solves the problem.  You should delete the answer you posted.  Since you did not provide accurate details of your problem, you should EDIT your original question and add details to your question that better describe your problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "next results from same line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the text that is after the colon.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G in ('find /I "this is dummy text" ^<C:\x.txt') DO set var=%%G
echo %var%
```

Comment: Thanks! With some adjustments it`s workin as i need.